# Anyone knows what coordinates this GLSL function would produce?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I am trying to experiment with pixel shaders in WPF, and I want to try out this code:

```
-1.0 + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy
```

But I am not sure what range of values that would produce. I am applying mine to image as a filter and I have access to u and v values [0-1]. When I do this:

```
-1.0 + 2.0 * {U,V};
```

I am not getting the same result. I know the above also must be a normalized value range but not sure if -1 to 1, or 0 to 1, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: U,V coordinates should be in the range [0,1]. If you multiply U with the texture width and V with the texture height, you get the pixel location that UV coordinate is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy` gives you the range [0,1].
- Multiplying by 2 gives you the range [0,2].
- Substracting 1 gives you the range [-1,1]

example:
http://glsl.heroku.com/e#7712.0

Comment: Thanks alot, appreciate it. I am basically trying this effect, but somehow my effect in certain time values end up offset from the screen, either partially or altogether (black screen). So basically the image moves away from the screen after a few seconds. Do you know how do they do it so it always seem to travel around the center of the image? It's applying pixel by pixel and so am I. Here is the link, radial blur: http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/

Comment: Without having studied the effect mechanics: i'd guess that's what the trigonometric functions are there for. Try playing around with the code there (and recompile with the compile button in your link) to get a feeling for what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

reading through this like a compiler would. `-1.0 + 2.0` get's reduced to `1.0`. The statment then becomes `1.0 * glFragCoord.xy / resolution.xy`. `1 * x = x`, given that, the equastion then becomes `glFragCoord.xy / resolution.xy`.

In effect, you're going to wind up with a range of [0, 1/resolution].

If What you mean the equasion to be is `-1.0 + (2.0 * glFragCoord.xy / resolution.xy)` then you have [0, 2/resolution], subracting 1 becomes [-1, (2/resolution)-1].

Comment: BODMAS (http://www.acronymfinder.com/Brackets-Order-Division-Multiply-Add-Subtract-(mnemonic-for-order-in-which-mathematical-calculations-are-done)-(BODMAS).html) applies to compilers as well. And the contents of gl_FragCoord vary. With earlier Pixelshader versions it was usually the screen dimension, like in the heroku example or the iquilezles example.